# SQL Server 2008 R2 / E-Mail if job doesn't run

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

In SQL Server 2008 R2 / Management Studio, I have a Job. The Job runs every day at 6:00 am. Sometimes the Job is crashing. I know taht it is possible to configure an E-Mail, if the job wasn't run.

How do I that and where? In Management Studio or directly on the Server 2008 R2?

THX.

Greetz
Vegeta

Comment: does 2008 have a "notifactions" section on the job properties window?

Comment: Yes, but I can't choose an E-Mail...

Comment: THX. And have a goog Weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS, go to management, then right click Database mail, and Configure Database Mail.  Here you need to set up a mail profile and enter your mail server details.

In SSMS, go to SQL Server Agent, then right click properties, and configure Alert System to Enable mail profile. SQL Server Agent must be restarted for this to take affect.

Now, in the SQL agent job properties, go to notifications, and you can select to email an account within your mail profile if a job fails

Comment: Where is "management"? There is File, Edit, View, Debug, Tools, Window, Community, Help

Comment: @Vegeta It's a folder under the server, at the same level as Security, Replication, SQL Server Agent..

Comment: THX :-) Have a goog Weekend :-)